# Find and replace in Notepad++ with specific text

Tags: python, hex, notepad++

I have xml file where i need to do some changes for an element.

```
<someElement name="Sometext">
```

I want to modify the above with an attribute like this

```
<someElement name="Sometext" newattribute="Sometext_8c54">
```

In the above i just want to copy the **name** attribute and create a **newattribute** which has the value of **name** attribute with **_4digitrandomhexadecimal**

How can I achieve this in notepad++

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: I was reading on the net, and thought it might be possible with python. But as I'm new to it don't know how to acheive this

Comment: You will need a text editor that supports scriptable macros such as `EmEditor`. I could answer this question if it is OK with `EmEditor`.

Comment: yes, kindly please do. It will add to the knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **EmEditor**, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the **Replace** dialog box, and enter:

**Find**: `<(.*?)name="(.*?)">`

**Replace with**: `\J "<\1name=\"\2\" newattribute=\"\2_" + (Math.floor(Math.random()*16)).toString(16) + (Math.floor(Math.random()*16)).toString(16) + (Math.floor(Math.random()*16)).toString(16) + (Math.floor(Math.random()*16)).toString(16) + "\">"`

set the **Regular Expressions** option, and click **Replace All**.

[image: EmEditor Replace dialog box]

**Explanation**

`\J` in the beginning of the **Replace with** string means that it is a JavaScript. `\1` and `\2` are back references referring to the first `(.*?)` and second `(.*?)` in the matched string. `(Math.floor(Math.random()*16)).toString(16)` is a random hexadecimal character.

References: http://www.emeditor.org/en/howto_search_replacement_expression_syntax.html

Comment: Can you please add the `emeditor` tag to your question? Thank you.